# How do I access a pod in another namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, okd

We have 2 namespaces, say namespace1 and namespace2.

The following are the services in namespace1 and the services exposed.

```
[root@console ~]# oc get svc
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
config-server              ClusterIP   172.30.8.152    <none>        8888/TCP   3h
eureka-server              ClusterIP   172.30.120.74   <none>        8761/TCP   3h
expedia-rapidapi-service   ClusterIP   172.30.236.3    <none>        8233/TCP   3h
travelcodes-service        ClusterIP   172.30.14.36    <none>        8084/TCP   3h
tti-service                ClusterIP   172.30.46.212   <none>        8245/TCP   2h
```

I can use nslookup lookup the cluster IP in any pod to the service "travelcodes-service"

```
/ $ nslookup travelcodes-service.contents.svc.cluster.local
Name:      travelcodes-service.contents.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 172.30.14.36 travelcodes-service.contents.svc.cluster.local
```

However, I can only use curl to access travelcodes-service if the pod is in namespace1 but not namespace2

```
curl 172.30.14.36:8084/ping
```

Is there anything I need to expose in order to let a pod in namespace2 to access "travelcodes-service" in namespace1?

Comment: The example you show all seems to be in a single namespace.  Do you have an example that demonstrates the more specific problem you're having?  What response do you get from the `curl` command?  In what context are you trying to run it?  Can you directly use the `service-name.namespace.name.svc.cluster.local` DNS name, instead of first resolving it by hand and then calling its IP address?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the service  in  with

```
<service1>.<namespace1>
```

For example you can use this url:

```
http://<service1>.<namespace1>.svc.cluster.local
```

More on that: [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services)

To get a list of all your namespaces:

```
oc get ns
```

And for a list of services in one namespace:

```
oc get services -n <namespace-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, services in a Kubernetes cluster are only accessible within their own namespace. To allow access to a service across namespaces, you can use Kubernetes Service DNS.
To enable access to the "travelcodes-service" in `namespace1` from a pod in `namespace2`:

1. Create a Service in namespace1 of type ExternalName that points to the DNS name of the "travelcodes-service" in `namespace1`.
2. Grant appropriate permissions to the pod in `namespace2` to access services across namespaces. This can be done by creating a `Role and RoleBinding` in `namespace2`.

After completing the above steps, the pod in `namespace2` should be able to access the "travelcodes-service" in `namespace1` using its `DNS name`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, NubDev! Many or most of your 23 answers in the last two weeks appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.